# Auto-filling other ImageFields based on the first one

Tags: python, django, model, django-models

I have to save 3 versions of uploaded photo (original one and two resized) and i don't want to use solr. 
Those two additional photos have to be represented as ImageFields in my model so i could use Django ORM.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    #...
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo_album")
    medium_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo_album/medium", null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo_album/thumbnails", null=True)
```

I have tried overriding save() method (photos in this case are the same size):

```
    def save(self):

        self.thumbnail.file = self.photo.file
        self.medium_photo.file = self.photo.file
        super(Post, self).save()
```

But it doesn't work(why?).

How can i auto-fill those additional ImageFields , in my model , before saving?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to fill other ImageField based on the first one (to create and save thumbnail based on the original photo in my case).

```
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import StringIO

class Post(models.Model):

    #...

    def save(self):

        thumb = Image.open(self.photo.file)
        thumb_io = StringIO.StringIO()
        thumb.save(thumb_io,format = thumb.format)
        self.thumbnail.save(self.photo.name, ContentFile(thumb_io.getvalue()), save=False)
        super(Post, self).save()
```

Don't forget to set `save` to `False` , otherwise it will start recursively adding same thumb over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

remove `.file` from `self.photo.file` like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import StringIO

def save(self):
    iamge_file = StringIO.StringIO(self.photo.read())
    image = Image.open(image_file)
    self.thumbnail.file = image
    self.medium_photo.file = image
    super(Post, self).save()
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It's doesn't save photos to designated folders.

Comment: @4evertoblerone check my edit. add `save(*args, **kwargs)` to end of `super(Post, self).save()`

Comment: Aren't *args and **kwargs used in definition of class methods/ functions and not in method/function calling? Btw it doesn't work.:)

Comment: I tried adding *args and **kwargs to my version of save as parameters and again it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that in your case you are touching database twice (create + update) and that you have one redundant IO operation (reading saved image to save/create  other versions). For me that is a no go. Isn't there some way to get photo from temp. variable and save whole Post object in one move?

Comment: Sorry, for not getting back at you sooner. I am little concerned about creating a new object (image), which serves only as a bridge so i could be able to set thumb/medimum_photo.file, and it's memory footprint. Is there a way for me to directly get from photo img (resize it) and set it to thumbnail/medium_photo fields. Are my concerns related to memory usage justified?